# Updating jar in docker image

Tags: spring, docker, spring-boot, dockerfile

I am building a Docker image with the below file.  It is a simple Spring Boot app.
When I make an update to the Spring project, I am rebuilding the image to get the updated image.  However, this is creating an entirely new image that is getting completely re-pushed up to the repo in it's entirety (700+MB).  How do I update an existing image to include the newly updated jar instead of a completely new image so that I don't have to push up 700+MB just to update the Spring app?

This is the dockerfile I am currently using:

```
FROM java:8
EXPOSE 8080
VOLUME /tmp
ADD app-name.1.0.jar app.jar
RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","app.jar"]
```

*Note:* When I run the **docker attach** command, it just sits there and does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you missed a point of docker containers/images. 
**New app version ==> new Docker image** is true path and sounds to be what you want.

And if only last layer is changed (that is the case with Dockerfile you provided)  *docker push* will only upload the new layer of the image. So in this case something about the size of app.jar...

Comment: Great, that was it.  I bumped the version number instead of re-building with the same version number.  As a result, it only pushed up the specific layer and not all of them again.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had to do this too.

1. Connect to your docker from host.
2. Stop java process in docker.
3. Exit docker from terminal
4. Upload your jar new version and replace the old jar.
5. Connect to your docker from host. See step 1.
6. Start java process.

Now details.

1) Open host command line or shell. Connect to your docker from host.

```
docker exec -it DOCKER_ID bash
```

To get DOCKER_ID, `docker ps`.

2) Find out the java process id and kill it.

`top` - find out process id.
`kill -9 PROCESS_ID` - kill it.

3) `exit` command on the bash from connected docker bash.

4) Upload and replace a jar in docker

```
docker cp java-app.jar  DOCKER_ID:/app/java-app.jar
```

Note, in your docker folder where your jar is can be different. It is `app` in my case.

5) See 1.

6) java -jar java-app.jar

Note, JAVA_HOME env variable should be defined when you prepared your image.